# What are the GPU requirements for XNA 4.0?

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0, directx9, compatibility

I tried to build a sample application using XNA, but I got an error saying that Pixel Shader 1.1 was required, so I got a used Radeon X300 GPU that supports Pixel Shader.
I tried to build it again, but I got another error saying that "Your current graphics card does not support the XNA HiDef profile" and would not build.

Since that card seems to not be compatible, I guess I need to buy another one. What features should I look for to make sure that it's compatible with XNA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a DirectX 10 compatible GPU for running `HiDef` XNA games. Just change your project settings to `Reach` or get a compatible graphics card.

You can find more info on the differences between HiDef and Reach on [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310004334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx) from Shawn Hargreaves.